# Issue in jQuery Datepicker while selecting Start date and End date

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using jQuery Datepicker and i have same change in jQuery but something went wrong in this.

All Working fine as my requirement but when I select date from `December 2020` in start date than all Dates of End date is disable.

And this is happing only when I select December 2020's dates.

```js
if (jQuery('#datetimepicker1').length > 0) {
    jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        lang: 'ch',
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        formatDate: 'Y/m/d',
        maxDate: 0,
        onChangeDateTime: function(dp, $input) {
            var from = $input.val().split("/");
            var f = new Date(from[2], from[1], from[0]);
            f.setDate(f.getDate());
            var datemin = f.getFullYear()+ "/" +f.getMonth()+ "/" +f.getDate();
            var datestr= from[2]+ "/" +f.getMonth()+ "/" +from[0];
            $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker({
                lang: 'ch',
                timepicker: false,
                format: 'd/m/Y',
                formatDate: 'Y/m/d',
                changeMonth: f.getMonth(),
                changeYear: f.getFullYear(),
                minDate: new Date(datemin),
                startDate:datemin,
            });
        }

    });
}

if (jQuery('#datetimepicker2').length > 0) {
    jQuery('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        lang: 'ch',
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        formatDate: 'Y/m/d',
        maxDate: 0,
    });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>


<input id="datetimepicker1" type="text" placeholder="Start Date"/>
<input id="datetimepicker2" type="text" placeholder="End Date"/>
```

Comment: I assume you have a mix up between formats (`Y/m/d`  and `d/m/Y`) so that there is no reasonable date, e.g `new Date("03","12","2020")` == `Mon Jul 12 1909`

Comment: sorry wrong, problem is probably that month seems to expect to be zero-based, e.g `new Date("2019","11","02")` == `Dec 02 2019`

Comment: @johnSmith Can you provide code? where i have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript months are `0`-based, but your input is `1`-based, so you need to convert

```
var f = new Date(from[2], from[1]-1, from[0]);
```

It fails as there's no 13th month, so gets "confused".

As you're not using the date itself, but reformatting back to a string, you also need to convert back on those lines:

```
var datemin = f.getFullYear()+ "/" +(f.getMonth()+1)+ "/" +f.getDate();
var datestr= from[2]+ "/" +(f.getMonth()+1)+ "/" +from[0];
```

```js
if (jQuery('#datetimepicker1').length > 0) {
    jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        lang: 'ch',
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        formatDate: 'Y/m/d',
        maxDate: 0,
        onChangeDateTime: function(dp, $input) {
            var from = $input.val().split("/");
            var f = new Date(from[2], from[1]-1, from[0]);
            f.setDate(f.getDate());
            var datemin = f.getFullYear()+ "/" +(f.getMonth()+1)+ "/" +f.getDate();
            var datestr= from[2]+ "/" +(f.getMonth()+1)+ "/" +from[0];
            $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker({
                lang: 'ch',
                timepicker: false,
                format: 'd/m/Y',
                formatDate: 'Y/m/d',
                changeMonth: f.getMonth(),
                changeYear: f.getFullYear(),
                minDate: new Date(datemin),
                startDate:datemin,
            });
        }

    });
}

if (jQuery('#datetimepicker2').length > 0) {
    jQuery('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        lang: 'ch',
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        formatDate: 'Y/m/d',
        maxDate: 0,
    });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>


<input id="datetimepicker1" type="text" placeholder="Start Date"/>
<input id="datetimepicker2" type="text" placeholder="End Date"/>
```